# Place a window (borderless) on top (z-index) of another window (borderless) such that the one on top trails the one on the bottom

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

The concept of DWM window manipulation/Window Styles is a bit new to me and I am experimenting with a few new situations. I would be obliged if someone could help point me in the right direction.

Also, how do you keep the 2nd window exactly behind the 1st instead of another window from another application in between them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need process the [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message on one of the windows and use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure you keep the z-order. You can either use SetWindowPos to send the window below a message that it should precede the current window, or call it from the second window to the first one with the HWND_TOP argument when the z-order changes.

Comment: How would a SetWindowPos that you are talking to look like? Can you provide the psuedocode for the parameters?

Comment: if (msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING){if((WNDPOS*)lparam)->hwndInsertAfter != lastWindowPos) SetWindowPos(otherWindowHwnd, hwnd, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)} for the upper window, you have to change the first two parameters for setwindowpos if you do this from the lower window

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. But when I tried to do the borderless window, I lost ability to bring it into focus/active window. So if I click on it, the window never came back to the front. Is that a normal response from a borderless window? Can I avoid it?

Comment: would passing WS_CHILD to the CreateWindow call for the borderless window having the other window as parent HWND solve what you are trying? it would look something like borderlessWnd = CreateWindow("ClassName", "Window Title", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 300, 300, parentWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

Comment: By any chance do you know how to make a window transparent and draw opaque pixels onto the transparent surface using direct2d?

Comment: You can't mix stuff that direct2d draws with what win32 draws, you have to make a direct2d surface and do everything from there.

Comment: I posted this question on stack. Can you please take a look at it, that would be so appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836921/id2d1hwndrendertarget-always-having-black-background-instead-of-transparent